# What letters are used in different European languages for naming things by letters?

Tags: alphabets

What letters are used in different European languages for naming things by letters? In Finnish, all 29 letters (also Å, Ä, Ö) are used in naming. But in Czech, letters with diacritics (e.g. Á, Š, Ů) are not used. For example, are special letters also used in e.g. Turkish, Icelandic, Slovene, etc.?

Comment: What do you mean by "naming things"? In Finnish, the letter ä is used to name the noun known in English as "lake" and in Finnish as järvi. In Czech, the plant known in English as "sage" is named Šalvěj, using the letters š and ě. So letters with diacritics *are* used to name things in Czech. I surmise you must have a special meaning in mind for "naming things".

Comment: When you enumerate by letters, German typography uses only a–z, and when more letters are needed, the continuation is aa, ab, ... . But this is not really a linguistic question, but a question on typographical tradition. [graphicdesign.se], perhaps?

Comment: I meant what letters are used in enumeration.

Comment: Since we answer questions about different writing systems here, I think this is on-topic, though I'm not sure linguists are the best people to answer it. Typographers are more likely to know.

Comment: Using letters like numbers has a long tradition, thousands of years.

Comment: I assume specifically you mean to name items in sequences, eg Building A.

Comment: In Russian it’s definitely not the full set, hence the implied absurdity of *Операция «Ы»*.

Comment: It's not just diacritics. In Welsh 'dd', 'll', 'ff' and 'ng', 'ch', 'th', and 'ph' are regarded as letters, and alphabetized as such. I presume that if the letters are usedas an index for an enumeration they do likewise, though I haven't found any direct evidence either way.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer: OTOH, after Russia eliminated four redundant letters (ІѢѲѴ) from its alphabet in 1918, the railroads continued to use these letters to name [locomotives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Russian_steam_locomotive_classes) for several more decades.

Comment: @dan04 Interesting!  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ы_(паровоз) also exists.